# How to change the image of imagebutton on every Click?

Tags: android

I'm making a puzzle word matching game in Android. My requirement is to change the image of imagebutton on click, and then if the imagebutton is clicked again, I want to display the previous image. This should be done on every click, Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use variable to keep track of button clicks or store currently assigned image ID as tag of the button object. After that just check the value in the onClickListener and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a flag indicating the state of the flag.

Then set an `onClickListener` and do something like:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    state = !state;
    imageView. setImageResource(state ? R.drawable.image1 : R.drawable.image2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [setImageResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) method.